# .htaccess pagination redirect rule in wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, woocommerce

people!

I want to change the url from "https://some-domain.com/.../?product-page=some-page-number" to "https://some-domain.com/.../page/some-page-number" to make every dynamic page static for caching purposes.

This is happened only when I use [shordcodes] to show specific product categories and tags in custom made pages. I`m change Settings -> Permalinks -> Custom Structure and enter the structure you want to use, there`s everything fine.

I try a lot of scenarios in functions.php and in .htaccess file, but nothing work for me.

Can somebody help?

I try a lot of scenarios in functions.php and in .htaccess file, but nothing work for me.

Something like:

```
 RewriteRule ^/page/(.*)$ ?product-page=$1 [R=301,L]
```

and other variants, but every time nothing happening

Answer (score 0):

```
function custom_product_permalink_structure($permalink, $post, $leavename, $sample) {
    if ($post->post_type == 'product' && is_numeric($post->ID)) {
        $permalink = home_url("/.../page/{$post->ID}/");
    }
    return $permalink;
}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'custom_product_permalink_structure', 10, 4);

function custom_product_rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $new_rules = array();
    $new_rules['.../page/([0-9]+)/?$'] = 'index.php?product=$matches[1]';
    return $new_rules + $rules;
}

add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'custom_product_rewrite_rules');
```

Replace .../page/ with your desired URL structure. Please see if this works???

Comment: I thing your answer it`s not gonna help! My case is online-shop with woocommerce.                   https://www.andi-design.eu/абсорбатори/?product-page=2 and i want to change the "/?product-page=some-number" with "/page/some-number". This is happened, because i use shortcodes to show specific products = [product ......... paginate=true ]

Comment: In that case in wp admin in custom url put this /%category%/%postname%/page/%paged%/

Comment: and add this function function custom_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^your-slug/page/([^/]*)/?','index.php?category_name=абсорбатори&paged=$matches[1]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rules');

Comment: Nothing happenes, It`s from the .htacces file.......there must RewriteRule with some code